# Linear equation for a great circle on a (multidimensional) sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, spherical-geometry

Can we introduce independent coordinates on a sphere such that **any** great circle could be represented as a linear equation (like line on the plane)? If yes, what is a generalization for higher dimensions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "multidimensional" are you then talking about great hypercircles (or whatever they would be called)?  The intersection of a hyperplane with the sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done locally by projection from the center of the sphere. Great circles go to lines, so if you pull back the cartesian coordinates from the plane to a hemisphere, every great half-circle is described by a linear equation.

You cannot extend this beyond the hemisphere, because two great circles meet in two points, but a system of linear equations cannot have two solutions.